# Get URL file property from a Windows internet shortcut (.url) file

Tags: python-2.7

I want to retrieve the URL property of a Windows internet shortcut (.url) file.  For example, there is a YouTube trailer "ROGUE ONE: A Star Wars Story TRAILER (2016)" at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ze2kpOZx_kU.  If the URL is dragged from a Chrome browser to the Windows desktop a file "ROGUE ONE- A Star Wars Story TRAILER (2016) - YouTube.url" is created.  In Windows 10 I can look at the file's property (e.g. right click and select 'Property'), select the 'Web Document' tab, and in the URL field there is "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ze2kpOZx_kU".  How do I get this URL programmtically in Python 2.7?

Comment: Try `open()` the file directly in Python and probably you can paste the `read()` result here (sorry I don't have a Windows PC). I'm not familiar with the format of windows `.url` file but it must store the URL in the file someway.

Comment: @Philip - Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was chasing this problem the wrong way!  I thought I needed to extract the file information.  Using Philip's suggestion I printed the contents and saw that the URL was inside.  For example, dragging the movie's URL to C:\Temp and running the following I got the URL:

```
filename = 'C:\Temp\ROGUE ONE- A Star Wars Story TRAILER (2016) - YouTube.url'
with open(filename, "r") as infile:
    for line in infile:
        if (line.startswith('URL')):
            url = line[4:]
            break
print url
```

This gives:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ze2kpOZx_kU

Answer (score 2):

Windows Internet Shortcut (`.url`) files are INI files. They may have one or more sections (for apps or frames) and several properties (like `IconFile` or `HotKey`) but they always have an `InternetShortcut` section with a `URL` property.

So you can parse them with `ConfigParser`:

```
import ConfigParser

parser = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()

file = 'C:\Temp\ROGUE ONE- A Star Wars Story TRAILER (2016) - YouTube.url'
parser.read(file)
url = parser.get('InternetShortcut', 'url', True)
```

Arguments in `get` are:

1. Section.
2. Option.
3. `raw`: `True` disables interpolation. Needed to avoid mistaking url's percent-encoding for inner references.

Answer (score 0):

I've extracted all url strings from multiples `.url` files as below Python 3.9.5 script:

```
import glob
import os

for filename in glob.glob('*.url'):
 with open(filename, "r") as infile:
    for line in infile:
        if (line.startswith('URL')):
            url = line[4:]
            print (url)
            break
```

Note: save the above script as `.py` file inside same folder that contain `.url` files.